# How can I achieve a row item when someone replies to a message, similar to Discord, in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to set up UI like Discord when someone replies a message and I out of idea to design.

Below image is an example. Above is my UI, and below is the Discord UI when someone replies. I already high light with red border.
[image]

I want to set up the line drawing from the avatar of ListTitle to the Container above, similar to the Discord UI.

Here is my current design

```
return Column(
                children: [
                  chatItem.replyMessage != null
                      ? Container(
                          child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text("${chatItem.replyMessage}")),
                        )
                      : SizedBox(),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      child: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
                    ),
                    title: Text("${chatItem.message}"),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "${chatItem.time}",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
```

Thanks